# SqlException: Invalid object name ERROR WHILE BUILDING WEBSITE IN C# (VISUAL STUDIO) and sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, web, web-development-server

New to WebDev ,
Tried to make a website where farmers can order medicines from stores online.

In a single solution, 2 projects were made Medicine.Model(The database was called here from the sqlsever)  and Medicine.WEB(the above project is added here as a *PROJECT REFERENCE*)

3 Models

Farmer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace Medicine.Model.Models
{
    public partial class Farmer
    {
        public Farmer()
        {
            Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        }

        public string FarmerName { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int FarmerId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Store

```
 public partial class Store
    {
        public Store()
        {
            Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        }

        public int StoreId { get; set; }
        public string StoreName { get; set; }
        public string StoreLocation { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

Order(Stores the order details and links the above to tables)

```
public partial class Order
    {
        public int FarmerId { get; set; }
        public int StoreId { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string DateOfOrder { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        public virtual Farmer Farmer { get; set; }
        public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
    }
```

Made changes in the shared layout view to add the 3 controllers.

Made 3 controllers respectively

here is the shared layout code

```
<li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Farmers" asp-action="Index">Farmers</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Index">Orders</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Store" asp-action="Index">Stores</a>
                        </li>
```

**OK , so the problem is that the website runs perfectly fine when i click on home but when i click farmer in website then it shows the following error.**

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Invalid object name 'Farmer'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__169_0(Task result)

*//Error also shows redline here*

Medicine.WEB.Controllers.FarmersController.Index() in FarmersController.cs

```
        return View(await _context.Farmers.ToListAsync());
```

**So i am adding the entire Farmer Controller Here,**

FarmersController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Medicine.Model.Models;

namespace Medicine.WEB.Controllers
{
    public class FarmersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MedicinesDBContext _context;

        public FarmersController(MedicinesDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Farmers
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Farmers.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Farmers/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var farmer = await _context.Farmers
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FarmerId == id);
            if (farmer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(farmer);
        }

        // GET: Farmers/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Farmers/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("FarmerName,Location,Quantity,FarmerId")] Farmer farmer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(farmer);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(farmer);
        }

        // GET: Farmers/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var farmer = await _context.Farmers.FindAsync(id);
            if (farmer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(farmer);
        }

        // POST: Farmers/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("FarmerName,Location,Quantity,FarmerId")] Farmer farmer)
        {
            if (id != farmer.FarmerId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(farmer);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!FarmerExists(farmer.FarmerId))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(farmer);
        }

        // GET: Farmers/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var farmer = await _context.Farmers
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FarmerId == id);
            if (farmer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(farmer);
        }

        // POST: Farmers/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var farmer = await _context.Farmers.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Farmers.Remove(farmer);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool FarmerExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Farmers.Any(e => e.FarmerId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me where my mistake is and how to correct it ?

Comment: Creating `MedicinesDBContext` doesn't automatically create the tables.  You need to use DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated or Migrations or manually create the target tables.

Comment: Yes , i have created already created the tables using sql server

Comment: How did you create the tables? EF may not be seeing them if you didn't use ef migrations and ef database update.

Answer (score 0):

Got it , See the models were made in the code from the database(sql server) so NuGet package console no error , the error was in connections string that we enter in appsetting.json, Thanks all